# Eclipse bug : javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file

Tags: java, eclipse, javax.imageio

The following code is running successfully in BlueJ IDE, but not in Eclipse.

```
String path="images/pic1.jpg";

BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My image path is same in both the IDE. Also, I observed directory structure is same for *.class file and image files.

Why this happens in eclipse only?

Comment: Is `"images/pic1.jpg"` an application resource?  An 'application resource' might be an icon used for a button or menu item, an application BG or splash, etc.  If so, the code is using an entirely wrong approach.  It should be accessing the image by URL from the run-time class-path.  Will explain further if intelligent questions are posed.

Comment: Before calling `read`, you should `assert` that the file exists, to rule out more possibilities of failure.

Comment: if i used runtime class-path then i should include images path to it. my question is that what is the correct approach to use images from files in java application?

Answer (score 4):

You must use

```
System.getProperty("user_dir")+File.separator+"image"+File.separator+"im0001.jpg";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an Eclipse bug. You need to copy the image files into the Eclipse Project Main Folder (not src subfolder).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your images folder is resource folder (which mean it is on the CLASSPATH) and write

```
  BufferedImage myPicture = null;
   try {
      myPicture = ImageIO.read("images/pic1.jpg");
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

or use the alternative.

```
   BufferedImage myPicture = null;
   try {
      myPicture = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/images/pic1.jpg"));
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: in BlueJ IDE both the code is works well. but in **Eclipse both are not running**.

Comment: ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/images/pic1.jpg")); is working in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse sets the default file location to the root bin folder, not to root or to the package folder. Make sure your files are in the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
String path="d:\\images\\pic1.jpg";

BufferedImage myPicture = null;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: IMO source code never needs more then one line of 'white space'.  This applies doubly to code posted to SO.

Comment: this is not a big deal!!  But it is **bad habit to use absolute path**. this code *will not run on other machine*.

Comment: please tell me solution of this.

Answer (score 0):

just check your image path with `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Answer (score 0):

Default libraries in eclipse does not support "ImageIO".